# Style multi page links (index.php?first_page) - PHP

Tags: php, css, hyperlink

I'm trying to figure out how to style my multi page links. I have a navbar in my index.php that opens other pages on the same page.
I have another navbar on which I have some style:

```
class="<?= basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == "multi_page.php" ? "selected" : ""; ?>" href="multi_page.php">Multisida</a>
```

This works for the normal links but I can't seem to use this on the multi page links. Am I doing it wrong? The link I want to style looks like this:

```
<a href="?page=index">Index</a>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from my teacher. I'd like to share it with you.

This is from the multipage.php:

```
<?php

$pageReference = $_GET["page"] ?? "index";

$multiPages = [
    "index" => [
        "title" => "Intro",
        "subpage" => __DIR__ . "/multipage/index.php",
    ],
    "print-get" => [
        "title" => "Print variable",
        "subpage" => __DIR__ . "/multipage/print-get.php",
    ]
];

$newPage = $multiPages[$pageReference] ?? null;
if (!$newPage) {
    die("Fel, fel, fel...");
}

$title = "{$newPage['title']}";
$m_subpage = $newPage["subpage"];
include __DIR__ . "/view/header.php";
include __DIR__ . "/view/multi_page.php";
include __DIR__ . "/view/footer.php";
```

From the view/multi_page.php:

```
<div class="wrap-main">

<h2>Multipage</h2>

<?php include __DIR__ . "/multi_aside.php"; ?>

<article class="subpage">
    <?php if ($pageReference) : ?>
        <?php require $m_subpage; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p>You have selected something '<?= htmlentities($pageReference) ?>' that 
        does not map to an actual page.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</article>    
</div>
```

From multipage_aside.php:

```
<aside>
<ul class="aside">
<?php foreach ($multiPages as $key => $value) : ?>
    <?php
    $selected = null;
    if ($key === $pageReference) {
        $selected = "class='selected'";
    }
    ?>
    <li><a <?= $selected ?> href="?page=<?= $key ?>"><?= $value["title"] ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>    
</aside>
```

And finally, the CSS:

```
.aside .selected {
color: purple;
font-weight: bolder;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```